# How to extract only main content from any web page? (without footer, menu bars,navigation bar, footer, side bar, breadcrumb)

Tags: php, data-extraction, html-content-extraction

I have extracted whole body content by using this code.
But I don't know have to Remove navigation bar, footer, side bar, breadcrumb. 
Can anyone suggest me how to get this done?

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
$bodycontent .= $dom->saveHTML($child); }
```

Comment: can you please print_r($bodycontent)? (Show us the content)

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like `readability`, which is implemented in many languages:

- https://github.com/j0k3r/php-readability
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/readability-lxml